# How to solve factorial equations with very big numbers

Tags: factorial, big-numbers

I have problem. I've calculated memory complexity of my algorithm. In exchange of very good time complexity of my algorithm, I have memory complexity $x!$, where $x$ is number of elements my algorithm gets.

Number of numbers I can easily store equals $2^{22000000}$. How many elements can my algorithm accept?

$x!=2^{22000000}$

How can I solve it? I've tried several calculators (even wolfram alpha), but no calculator was able to solve it. I've tried to use Stirling approximation ( [Solving equations with factorials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697277/solving-equations-with-factorials) ), but the number is just too big.

Do you know some online calculator that would be powerfull enough to calculate it? Or some other method to calculate it? I do not need exact number, I just want to know how big the number is (if I could tell number of digits in the number, it would be great).

Thanks, Peter

Comment: A crude approximation is $x! \approx (x/e)^x$. Solving for this gives:
$$
(\frac{x}{e})^x = 2^{22000000} \implies
x \ln (x)  -x = 22000000 \ln(2)
$$
Then using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NSolve%5Bx*Log%5Bx%5D-x%3D%3D22000000*Log%5B2%5D,x%5D) gives you an approximation.

Note also that taking first logarithm will help software to approximate the answer since it needs not to deal with extra huge number anymore. For example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindRoot%5BLog%5BGamma%5Bx%2B1%5D%5D+%3D%3D+22000000*Log%5B2%5D,%7Bx,10%5E6%7D%5D).

Comment: If you look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k , have a look at @robjohn's elegant solution for a similar problem.

Comment: You can easily store $2^22000000$ numbers? May I ask what kind of hardware you're using for that?

Comment: Take logarithms, use the loggamma and inverse loggamma function:
$$\log x! = \log\Gamma(x+1)=22000000\log(2)$$ $$ x= \mathrm{loggamma}^{-1}(22000000\log(2))-1= 1175108.399864\dots$$ 
The inverse loggamma function can be computed e.g. with Newtons method.

Comment: @Professor Vector I have a collection of numbers (like one row in excel full of numbers). But because of my algorithm structure, most of row will not be occupied, so I will physically store only few numbers (plus information which cells are occupied).

Comment: Thank you all! This helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2079043) is given the approximation
$$
n\sim e\exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(\frac1{e}\log\left(\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\right)\right)-\frac12
$$
Plugging in $n!=2^{22000000}$, we get $n\approx1175108.4$. Then
$$
1175108!\approx2^{21999991.937}
$$
and
$$
1175109!\approx2^{22000012.101}
$$

Comment: In fact, if we use the Gamma function, we get $$1175108.4! =\Gamma(1175109.4) \approx2^{22000000.003}$$

Comment: For computing purposes, you probably want to use $\exp(W(x))=x/W(x)$ to avoid calculating $\exp$.

Answer (score 2):

*A quick and dirty approximation.*

Considering the function $\log_2(x!)$ for $10^3 \leq x \leq 10^6$ (by steps of $10^3$) and considering a totally empirical model $a+b x^c$, a non linear regression gave
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -24230.2 & 415.912 & \{-25046,-23414\} \\
 b & 6.22383 & 0.005670 & \{6.21271,6.23496\} \\
 c & 1.07893 & 0.000065 & \{1.07880,1.07905\} \\
\end{array}$$ So, if $x!=2^k$, the solution will be
$$x=0.183666 (k+24230.2)^{0.926847}$$ For $k=22 \times 10^6$, this would lead to 
$x=1.17429\times 10^6$ which is not too bad compared to gammatester's exact result.

**Edit  after robjohn's answer**

Remembering that $z=W(z)\, e^{W(z)}$ and taking into account that equation $x!=2^k$ has to be solved for large values of $k$, we can make good approximations defining $$z=\frac{2k \log(2)-\log(2\pi)}{2e}\qquad L_1=\log(z)\qquad L_2=\log(L_1)$$ and use the truncated expansion given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) to get 
$$x\approx  \frac{e z} {L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac {L_2(6-9L_2+2L_2^2)}{6L_1^3}}-\frac 12$$ which, for $k=22 \times 10^6$,  would lead to $x=1175102$. Adding the next terms of the given expansion  would lead to more accurate values.